# How to modify a VVVVVV save

Tags: vvvvvv

I've been re-playing VVVVVV and am extremely irritated by the first of the intermission levels... I'd really like to skip them. I've beat them already, but it takes forever and isn't enjoyable. Is there any way to accomplish this? I tried godmode but the other guy can get stuck then and that's no fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit both your teleporter save file and quicksave save file to skip the intermission. This works for both Intermission 1 and Intermission 2.

First, you will have to locate your save file. This involves first locating your **VVVVVV customization directory**, where all progress for the game is stored. For version 2.0, 2.2, and *Make and Play*, they are all in the following directories:

- On Windows, this will be in *`%USERPROFILE%`*`\Documents\VVVVVV` (`Documents` will be `My Documents` on Windows XP).
- On macOS, this will be in `/Users/`*`<username>`*`/Documents/VVVVVV`.
- On Linux, this will be in `~/.vvvvvv` for 2.0 and `~/.local/share/VVVVVV` for 2.2 and *Make and Play*.

The save files will then be in `saves/`.

The teleporter save file is `tsave.vvv` and the quicksave save file is `qsave.vvv`.

Before editing, **make sure that you've saved the progress of rescuing your crewmate. Teleporters only appear at the end of levels and intermissions, meaning that the teleporter auto-save won't happen after you save the crewmate**. Instead, you should quicksave at the start of the intermission, and then edit `qsave.vvv`.

To edit one of them to skip the intermission, open up the save file, and you'll see that it's actually an XML document. Set the following XML tags to these specific values:

- `<savex>` is 160
- `<savey>` is 153

  - These put Viridian in the proper position in the room, ensuring they will not get stuck in any walls.
- `<saverx>` is 102
- `<savery>` is 111

  - These will set the room to be the teleporter room in The Ship. Note that there is an `r` in these tags, as opposed to the two tags above.
- `<finalmode>` is 0

  - **This is very important!** This disables finalmode, i.e. loading the map named Outside Dimension VVVVVV, which contains both intermissions and The Final Level. In other words, if you don't set this to 0, you will be stuck inside the weird gray place and unable to return to Dimension VVVVVV without restarting.

Obviously, don't touch anything else unless you know what they do, or you could lose your progress.

Save the edits to the file `qsave.vvv`, load your quicksave, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange!

Comment: Thank you! I know a lot about the internals and technical details of VVVVVV, so that's why I answered

Answer (score 1):

There is no current way to skip or modify them. You could use a save that someone may have uploaded to the internet that has gone past thoes levels.